# Angular factory $scope becomes unbounded

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a factory which returns an object which I want to display in the front-end. There is some strange behaviour (to me at least) when I set a variable as follows:

I have set a variable 'returnObject' at the start of the controller and I then later assign it within a function that the factory outputs:

```
module.factory("MyFactory", function ($http, $timeout, $cookies) {

    var returnObject = {};

    var myFunction = function(response) {

        // un-coomment this and it doesn't work
        // var test = {1: 'test 2'};
        // returnObject = test;

        // this works
        returnObject[1] = 'test';
       
    }

    var poller = function() {
        $http.get('data.json').then(function(response) {
            $timeout(poller, 5000);
            myFunction(response);
        });
        return returnObject;    
    };   

    return {
        unreadMessagePoller: poller,
    };

});
```

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', MainCtrl);
function MainCtrl($scope, PollingService) {
    // poll for unread messages
    $scope.test = PollingService.unreadMessagePoller();
};
```

If I output the $scope variable in my template I see the object as expected. However if I un-comment the following lines:

```
var test = {1: 'test 2'};
returnObject = test;
```

It seems that the scope is unbound and the front-end output is empty. I just don't get it!

I created a plunker to demonstrate the problem.

https://plnkr.co/edit/feVaotKCE9w2uQLJ

UPDATE:

Here is another plunker different approach same behaviour, seems to me this is a bug:

https://plnkr.co/edit/hEtPNWkkl5ZudEuB

Answer (score 0):

```
$scope.test = PollingService.unreadMessagePoller();
```

Returns the *original* object `var returnObject = {};`

The code:

```
$http.get('data.json').then(function(response) {
     returnObject[1] = 'test';        
});
```

Modifies the *contents* of the *original* object.

On the other hand the code:

```
$http.get('data.json').then(function(response) {
    var test = {1: 'test 2'};
    returnObject = test;
});
```

**Replaces** the object reference in the factory with a *new* object reference.

Since the controller has the *original* object reference, it does not see the changed object reference.

This is the way that JavaScript works.

Frankly, the technique of returning an empty object and then filling in the contents when the data arrives from the server is a technique that I avoid. The technique was popular in the early days of AngularJS but now newer APIs return promises rather than empty objects that mutate.

Comment: Does this look better with promise: https://plnkr.co/edit/Sm8eDHtpDaIShFf1 - I actually already tried adding a promise but I added it to the function that is called by the main function which the service exposes!

Comment: ES6 Promises are not integrated with the AngularJS framework and its digest cycle. AngularJS modifies the normal JavaScript flow by providing its own event processing loop. This splits the JavaScript into classical and AngularJS execution context. Only operations which are applied in the AngularJS execution context will benefit from AngularJS data-binding, exception handling, property watching, etc.

Comment: I'm still how to overw-rite the object without it being a reference - angular.copy() perhaps? On each iteration the contents of the object can change, I thought rather than searching for the differences and removing them the quickest and easiest approach would be to make a single assignment to remove the previous object data?

Comment: The `$resource` service uses `angular.copy` to fill in the contents of the $resource object when the data arrives from the server. The $resource object also has a property named `$promise` which contains the promise returned by the $http service.